# Load Animation with Texture Packer in andengine

Tags: android, andengine, texturepacker

I use Texture Packer. I have `.pvr.ccz` file there are 10 frames.

I need to create an `AnimatedSprite` with this animation, but TexturePacker extension return only `TextureRegion` files.

How I can create `TiledTextureRegion` from this file?

Comment: Remember that `pvr` textures will not work in every android device.

Comment: Check this link: http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/understanding-texture-compression/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public TiledTextureRegion getTiledTextureFromPack(String name) {
    TexturePackTextureRegionLibrary packer;
    TexturePack spritesheetTexturePack;
    try {
        spritesheetTexturePack = new TexturePackLoader(game.getTextureManager(), "packs/")
                .loadFromAsset(game.getAssets(), name + ".xml");
        spritesheetTexturePack.loadTexture();
        this.packer = spritesheetTexturePack.getTexturePackTextureRegionLibrary();
    } catch (final TexturePackParseException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

    TexturePackerTextureRegion[] obj = new TexturePackerTextureRegion[this.packer
            .getIDMapping().size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.packer.getIDMapping().size(); i++) {
        obj[i] = this.packer.get(i);
    }

    TiledTextureRegion texture = new TiledTextureRegion(spritesheetTexturePack.getTexture(),
            obj);

    return texture;
}
```

I found solution