# How to load spritesheet from SD card in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, android-animation, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I am new to AndEngine. I'm trying to play an animation by using the spritesheet(generated using TexturePacker) and I successfully animated by referring this question ([Load Animation with Texture Packer in andengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311149/load-animation-with-texture-packer-in-andengine/9391731#9391731))

Q 1. How to load spritesheet and xml files from the SD card. (In above example spritesheet and xml files are loading from the Asset folder).

Q 2. I want to add sound to the animation. Is there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Havent tried this but you have the ability to set the base path for your assets using`BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");` Try changing from gfx to the path on your SD card.

Yes, you can add sounds

Drop your sound files (ogg) into res\raw folder and use the following code

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), soundType);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.start();
```